# All function calls made ahead of time

Tags: asynchronous, cypress

I wrote a function in one of my tests. I call this function in several parts of my test. All three function calls are made at the beginning of the test, one after another, regardless of when I called them in my test.

The code looks something like this:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
  console.log('Do something')
  // ...
}

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('Bar', () => {
    // Some tests...
    doSomething()
    // Some tests...
    doSomething()
    // Some tests...
    doSomething()
  })
})
```

In my output, I see the logs of the `doSomething()` three times, one after the other, before any of the test parts run.

How can I avoid these function calls being evaluated ahead of time?

Comment: That _"weird reason"_ is how Cypress works, the methods like `cy.get` add commands to the queue of actions to perform, they don't block on that action actually getting performed. You can make a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands), chain your function calls in a [closure](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Closures), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress performs all the actions [asynchronously](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous).

So if you want to do some action synchronously, you can wrap you code inside a `then` callback:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
  cy.wrap(null).then(() => {
    console.log('Do something')
  // ...
  })
}
```

Please also note that any cypress command may be issued directly in the test run time:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
  cy.log('Do something')
  // ...
}
```

Cypress will only enqueue the log command and execute it asynchronously in the cypress event loop.

Answer (score 4):

Already mentioned, the `.then()` callback schedules your code, but chain it off the test code that it should follow.

```js
describe('Foo', () => {
  it('Bar', () => {

    // Some tests...
    cy.get(...)
      .should(...)
      .then(() => doSomething())

    // Some tests...
    cy.get(...)
      .should(...)
      .then(() => doSomething())

  })
})
```